# Generar XML y leerlo como string en PHP

Tags: php, xml

Estoy generando un XML a partir de una consulta a una base de datos mysql.
Pero no logro generar el texto en formato xml y guardarlo en una variable como string, ya que solo he logrado primero guardarlo en un archivo.xml y luego leer el archivo, sin embargo, al leer este archivo no puedo obtener toda la estructura del xml sino solo del texto.

Tengo una función para crear el XML, en lugar de tener que generar el archivo, ¿cómo podría solo generar el string de la estructura del XML?

```
function CrearXML()
{
  $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');

  $doc->formatOutput = true;

  $raiz = $doc->createElement("USUARIOS");
  $raiz = $doc->appendChild($raiz);

  $usuario = $doc->createElement("USUARIO");
  $usuario = $raiz->appendChild($usuario);

  $id = $doc->createElement("ID");
  $id = $usuario->appendChild($id);
  $textId = $doc->createTextNode(1);
  $textId = $id->appendChild($textId);

  $nombre = $doc->createElement("NOMBRE");
  $nombre = $usuario->appendChild($nombre);
  $textNombre = $doc->createTextNode("Sergio");
  $textNombre = $nombre->appendChild($textNombre);

  $telefono = $doc->createElement("TELEFONO");
  $telefono = $usuario->appendChild($telefono);
  $textTelefono = $doc->createTextNode("4324245432");
  $textTelefono = $telefono->appendChild($textTelefono);

  $email = $doc->createElement("EMAIL");
  $email = $usuario->appendChild($email);
  $textEmail = $doc->createTextNode("sergio@hola.es");
  $textEmail = $email->appendChild($textEmail);

  $edad = $doc->createElement("EDAD");
  $edad = $usuario->appendChild($edad);
  $textEdad = $doc->createTextNode("26");
  $textEdad = $edad->appendChild($textEdad);

  echo 'Escrito: ' . $doc->save("xmlFELGenerados/usuarios.xml") . 'bytes <br><br>';

}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara, me parece que falta un detalle importante: ¿qué quieres como resultado final, un archivo `.xml` para guardarlo / transferirlo / descargarlo a otro lugar? La duda surge porque dices que quieres guardar los datos *como string*, ¿con qué fines exactamente? Si el rendimiento es importante, podrías considerar el uso de [`XMLWritter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php), en cualquier caso, todo depende del resultado final que esperas, lo cual no queda para nada claro en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [saveXML()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/domdocument.savexml.php) y mediante un `return` devolverlo al final de la función.

Sería algo así como:

```
<?php
function CrearXML()
{
  $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');

  $doc->formatOutput = true;

  $raiz = $doc->createElement("USUARIOS");
  $raiz = $doc->appendChild($raiz);

  $usuario = $doc->createElement("USUARIO");
  $usuario = $raiz->appendChild($usuario);

  $id = $doc->createElement("ID");
  $id = $usuario->appendChild($id);
  $textId = $doc->createTextNode(1);
  $textId = $id->appendChild($textId);

  $nombre = $doc->createElement("NOMBRE");
  $nombre = $usuario->appendChild($nombre);
  $textNombre = $doc->createTextNode("Sergio");
  $textNombre = $nombre->appendChild($textNombre);

  $telefono = $doc->createElement("TELEFONO");
  $telefono = $usuario->appendChild($telefono);
  $textTelefono = $doc->createTextNode("4324245432");
  $textTelefono = $telefono->appendChild($textTelefono);

  $email = $doc->createElement("EMAIL");
  $email = $usuario->appendChild($email);
  $textEmail = $doc->createTextNode("sergio@hola.es");
  $textEmail = $email->appendChild($textEmail);

  $edad = $doc->createElement("EDAD");
  $edad = $usuario->appendChild($edad);
  $textEdad = $doc->createTextNode("26");
  $textEdad = $edad->appendChild($textEdad);

  // echo 'Escrito: ' . $doc->save("xmlFELGenerados/usuarios.xml") . 'bytes <br><br>';
  return $doc->saveXML();

}
$var = CrearXML();
echo $var;
```

Lo cual te devolvería:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<USUARIOS>
  <USUARIO>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <NOMBRE>Sergio</NOMBRE>
    <TELEFONO>4324245432</TELEFONO>
    <EMAIL>sergio@hola.es</EMAIL>
    <EDAD>26</EDAD>
  </USUARIO>
</USUARIOS>
```